# A Java program to search in binary files

Tags: java, file, search, binary, adt

I want to write a program that makes a binary search in a file.

I have a TreeSet ADT that has strings int and I want to search in the file for each string this way: First I want to read the middle page of the file and search it. If the string is found, then the position of the string is returned; if not, then I want to read the page from the left or right half of the file depending on the alphabetical order of the strings.

My code for the class of the binary search is:

```
public class PageBinarySearch {
    final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    final int BOUND_LIMIT = -1;
    final int EVRTHG_OK = 0;
    final int ON = 1;
    final int OFF = 0;
    private DataInputStream inFile;
    private String[] readBuffer; //This buffer is used to read a specified page from
                              //the disk.
    private String[] auxBuffer;  //Auxiliary buffer is used for searching in the la-
                              //st page. This buffer has less than PAGE_SIZE ele-
                              //ments.
    private int lastPage, leftElemNum, lastPageNo;
    private int diskAccessMeter; //This variable is used to count disk accesses.
    private int firstNum;


/********************************************************************************/
    //Constructor of the class
    public PageBinarySearch(String filename, String key, int PageSize, int numPage, int numOfWords) throws IOException{
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Binary Search on disk pages");
        System.out.println("*************************************************");
        System.out.println();
        //Initializing the elements of the class.
        readBuffer = new String[PageSize];
        lastPage = numPage*PageSize;
        leftElemNum = numOfWords-(lastPage);
        auxBuffer = new String[leftElemNum];
        lastPageNo = numPage;
        diskAccessMeter = 0;
        this.setFirstNum(filename);
        basicPageBinarySearchMethod(filename, 0, lastPageNo, key,PageSize,numPage,numOfWords);
        System.out.println("Disk accesses:"+this.getDiskAccessMeter());
    }


/********************************************************************************/
    //Recursive binary search on disk pages.
    public void basicPageBinarySearchMethod(String filename, int start, int end,
                                            String key, int PageSize, int numPage, int numOfWords) throws IOException{
        inFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

        int bound = boundHandler(start, key);
        if (bound != EVRTHG_OK){return;}

        int midPage = start + (end-start)/2;
        int midPageIndex = ((midPage) * (PageSize));
        int midPageEnd = midPageIndex + PageSize;

        //System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Page:"+(midPage+1));
        System.out.println(" Index:"+midPageIndex+" End:"+midPageEnd);

        //Accessing midPage's index.
        accessPageIndex(midPageIndex - 1);

        fillBasicBuffer(PageSize);
        System.out.println();

        if (key.compareTo(readBuffer[0])<0){
            //Case that the key is in the left part.
            end = midPage - 1;
            inFile.close(); //We close the stream because in the next recursion
                            //we want to access new midPage.
            basicPageBinarySearchMethod(filename, start, end, key, PageSize, numPage, numOfWords);
        }
        else if (key.compareTo(readBuffer[255])>0){
            //Case that the key is in the left part.
            start = midPage+1;
            inFile.close();
            basicPageBinarySearchMethod(filename, start, end, key, PageSize, numPage, numOfWords);
        }
        else{
            //Case that:
            //a) key is bigger than the integer, which is in the midPage-
            //Index position of the file, and
            //b) key is less than the integer, which is in the midPageEnd
            //position of the file.
            LookingOnPage(midPage, key);
        }


    }

/********************************************************************************/  
    public int boundHandler(int start, String key) throws IOException{
        if (start == this.getLastPageNo()){
            //In this case the program has to start searching in the last page, 
            //which has less than PAGE_SIZE elements. So we call the alternative
            //function "LookingOnLastPage".
            System.out.println("Start == End");
            accessPageIndex(this.getLastPage());
            LookingOnLastPage(key);
            return BOUND_LIMIT;
        }
        //if (key < this.getFirstNum()){

            //System.out.println("Key does not exist.");
            //return BOUND_LIMIT;
        //}

        return EVRTHG_OK;
    }

/********************************************************************************/
    //This function is running a binary search in the specified disk page, which
    //is saved in the readBuffer.
    public void LookingOnPage(int pageNo, String key) throws IOException{
        int i, result;
        System.out.println("Looking for key:"+key+" on page:"+(pageNo+1));
        result = myBinarySearch(key, readBuffer);
        if (result != -1){
            System.out.println("Key found on page:"+(pageNo+1));
            inFile.close();
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Key is not found");
            inFile.close();
            return;
        }
    }

/********************************************************************************/
    //This function is running a binary search in the last disk page, which
    //is saved in the auxBuffer.
    public void LookingOnLastPage(String key) throws IOException{
        int i, result;
        this.setDiskAccessMeter(this.getDiskAccessMeter()+1);
        System.out.println("Looking for key:"+key+" on last page:"
                                                    +(this.getLastPageNo()+1));
        for (i=0; i<this.getLeftElemNum(); i++){
            auxBuffer[i] = inFile.readUTF();
        }
        result = myBinarySearch(key, auxBuffer);
        if (result != -1){
            System.out.println("Key found on last page");
            inFile.close();
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Key is not found");
            inFile.close();
            return;
        }
    }

/********************************************************************************/  
    public void accessPageIndex(int intNum) throws IOException
    {
        //This function is skipping intNum integers in the file, to access page's
        //index.
        int i;
        System.out.println(" Accessing page's index...");
        inFile.skipBytes(intNum*4);
        //inFile.readInt();
    }

/********************************************************************************/  
    public void fillBasicBuffer(int PageSize) throws IOException{
        //Loading readBuffer.
        int i;
        this.setDiskAccessMeter(this.getDiskAccessMeter()+1);
        for (i=0; i<PageSize; i++){
            readBuffer[i] = inFile.readUTF();
        }
    }

/********************************************************************************/  
    //This function implements binary search on a given buffer. 
    public int myBinarySearch(String key, String[] auxBuffer) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = auxBuffer.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if      (key.compareTo(auxBuffer[mid])<0) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key.compareTo(auxBuffer[mid])>0) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

/********************************************************************************/
    public int getLastPage() {
        return lastPage;
    }
    public void setLastPage(int lastPage) {
        this.lastPage = lastPage;
    }

    public int getLeftElemNum() {
        return leftElemNum;
    }
    public void setLeftElemNum(int leftElemNum) {
        this.leftElemNum = leftElemNum;
    }

    public int getLastPageNo() {
        return lastPageNo;
    }
    public void setLastPageNo(int lastPageNo) {
        this.lastPageNo = lastPageNo;
    }

    public int getDiskAccessMeter() {
        return diskAccessMeter;
    }
    public void setDiskAccessMeter(int diskAccessMeter) {
        this.diskAccessMeter = diskAccessMeter;
    }


    public int getFirstNum() {
        return firstNum;
    }


    public void setFirstNum(String filename) throws IOException {
        inFile = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        this.firstNum = inFile.readInt();
        inFile.close();
    }

}
```

and my main is :

```
public class MyMain {

    private static final int DataPageSize = 128; // Default Data Page size

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TreeSet<DictPage> listOfWords = new TreeSet<DictPage>(new MyDictPageComp());
        LinkedList<Page> Eurethrio = new LinkedList<Page>();

        File file = new File("C:\\Kennedy.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        //This will reference one line at a time...
        String line = null;
        int line_count=0; //Metavliti gia na metrame grammes ..
        int byte_count; //Metavliti gia na metrame bytes...
        int total_byte_count=0; //Metavliti gia synoliko arithmo bytes ...
        int fromIndex;

        int middleP;
        int kat = 0;
        while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){
            line_count++;
            fromIndex=0;
            String [] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
            String line_rest=line;
            for (int i=1; i <= tokens.length; i++) {
                byte_count = line_rest.indexOf(tokens[i-1]);
                fromIndex = fromIndex + byte_count + 1 + tokens[i-1].length();
                if (fromIndex < line.length())
                    line_rest = line.substring(fromIndex);
                listOfWords.add(new DictPage(tokens[i-1],kat));
                kat++;
                Eurethrio.add(new Page("Kennedy",fromIndex));
                }
                total_byte_count += fromIndex;
                Eurethrio.add(new Page("Kennedy", total_byte_count));
        }

        //for(DictPage p : listOfWords){
            //System.out.println(p.getWord() + " " + p.getPage());
        //}

        //for (int i = 0;i<Eurethrio.size();i++){
            //System.out.println(""+Eurethrio.get(i).getFile()+" "+Eurethrio.get(i).getBytes());
        //}

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(128) ;
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(bos);
        String s ;
        int integ;
        byte[] buf ;
        int nPag=1; //Aritmos selidwn
        int numOfWords=0;
        for (DictPage p : listOfWords){
            s = p.getWord();
            integ = p.getPage();
            numOfWords++;

            byte dst[] = new byte[20];
            byte[] src = s.getBytes(); //metatrepei se bytes to string
            System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 1, src.length); //to antigrafei ston buffer dst
            out.write(dst, 0, 20);  // to grafei sto arxeio

            out.writeInt(integ);  // grafei ton akeraio sto file

            out.close();

            buf = bos.toByteArray(); // Creates a newly allocated byte array.
            System.out.println("\nbuf size: " + buf.length + " bytes");
             //dhmiourgia selidas (h opoia einai enas byte array)
            if(buf.length> nPag*DataPageSize){
                nPag++;
            }
            byte[] DataPage = new byte[nPag*DataPageSize];
            System.arraycopy( buf, 0, DataPage, 0, buf.length); // antigrafw buf sth selida
            System.out.println("TARRARA"+DataPage.length);
            bos.close();//kleinw buf

            // write to the file
            RandomAccessFile MyFile = new RandomAccessFile ("newbabis", "rw");
            MyFile.seek(0);
            MyFile.write(DataPage);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Pages :"+nPag);
       if (nPag%2 == 0){
           middleP = nPag/2;
       }
       else{
           middleP = (nPag+1)/2;
       }
       System.out.println("Middle page is no:"+middleP);

       PageBinarySearch BinarySearch;
    String key;
    for(DictPage p : listOfWords){
        key = p.getWord();
        BinarySearch = new PageBinarySearch("C:\\Kennedy.txt", key , DataPageSize, nPag, numOfWords);
    }    
    }
}
```

My program is not working well, and I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @RomanC yes ..
at PageBinarySearch.<init>(PageBinarySearch.java:36)

Comment: You should add a stacktrace.

Comment: could you post your class DictPage and Page?

Comment: @jam the constructor is this:
public DictPage(String word, int page) {
  this.word = word;
  this.page = page;
 }
the only variables are the private word and page

Comment: @jam same for Page:
public Page(String file, int bytes) {
  this.file = file;
  this.bytes = bytes;
 }

Comment: and what about MyDictPageComp

Comment: import java.util.Comparator;
public class MyDictPageComp implements Comparator<DictPage>{
 @Override
 public int compare(DictPage arg0, DictPage arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return arg0.getWord().compareTo(arg1.getWord());
 }
}

Comment: what does your kennedy.txt contains ?

Comment: for example this is one f the sentences :
Vice President Johnson, Mr. Speaker, Mr. Chief Justice, President Eisenhower,

Comment: what is leftElemNum supposed to be ?
leftElemNum = numOfWords - (lastPage) ;

Comment: its the byte that are not used . it's (-numOfWords+(lastPage));
but this was not the problem eventually something else goes wrong

Comment: the problem seems to be, that you are reading the file with inFile.readUTF(). this can only be done if the file was written with DataOutputStream.writeUTF(...), if not use another stream instead of DataOutputStream

Comment: Whick method shall i use to read ?

Comment: @AsukaMatseli. Please [edit] clarifications, such as what errors you're seeing, into the body of the question. If you don't do that, this question will probably be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a buffered inputstream instead of your data inputstream
and adapt it's usage in your source code

since the readUTF method of the data inputstream will reach
end of file instantly if no data was written into a file with
the data outputstream method writeUTF or similiar.

note: this will not fix your program. it 
will lead to a stack overflow because your recursive
binary search method does'nt return

```
private BufferedInputStream inFile;

public void basicPageBinarySearchMethod(String filename, int start, int end,
                                        String key, int PageSize, int numPage, int numOfWords) throws IOException{
    inFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    ...
}

public void accessPageIndex(int intNum) throws IOException
{
    //This function is skipping intNum integers in the file, to access page's
    //index.
    int i;
    System.out.println(" Accessing page's index...");
    inFile.skip(intNum*4);
    //inFile.readInt();
}
 public void LookingOnLastPage(String key) throws IOException{
    int i, result;
    this.setDiskAccessMeter(this.getDiskAccessMeter()+1);
    System.out.println("Looking for key:"+key+" on last page:"
                                                +(this.getLastPageNo()+1));
    for (i=0; i<this.getLeftElemNum(); i++){
        auxBuffer[i] = String.valueOf((char)inFile.read());
    }
    ...
}
public void fillBasicBuffer(int PageSize) throws IOException{
    //Loading readBuffer.
    int i;
    this.setDiskAccessMeter(this.getDiskAccessMeter()+1);
    for (i=0; i < PageSize; i++){
        char c = (char)inFile.read();
        readBuffer[i] = String.valueOf(c);
    }
}

 public void setFirstNum(String filename) throws IOException {
    inFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    this.firstNum = inFile.read();
    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: how will i prevent the stack over flow ?

Comment: refactor your basicPageBinarySearchMethod so it will
terminate